# How to find Number of records inserted into sql table

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have following sql statement running in side stored procedure . This query inserts data into TABLE_AB, those data are retried from AAA and BBB table. When this procedure is running, I want to find out number of records inserted into TABLE_AB. If no data is included, I want to return now matching data was found to insert into TABLE_AB. Could anybody help to understand how to get it done. Thanks in advance for any help

> ```
> INSERT INTO TABLE_AB (X,Y,Z, TOTAL_CNT, TOTAL_AMT)
> SELECT X,Y,Z, TOTAL_CNT, TOTAL_AMT
> FROM(
>
> SELECT A.X, A.Y, A.Z , COUNT(1), SUM(AMT)
> FROM AAA A WHERE A.X = 1 
> GROUP BY A.X, A.Y, A.Z 
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT B.X, B.Y, B.Z , COUNT(1), SUM(AMT)
> FROM BBB B WHERE A.X = 1 
> GROUP BY B.X, B.Y, B.Z
>
> ) AS AB
> GROUP BY AB.X, AB.Y , AB.Z
> ```

Comment: You've tagged this for both Oracle and DB2.  Which database are you using?

Comment: @Justine, I'm using DB2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `SQL%ROWCOUNT`, you can achieve this. `SQL%ROWCOUNT` returns the number of rows effected from last successfully executed DML.

Usage:

```
DECLARE
  V_COUNT number;

BEGIN

INSERT INTO TABLE_AB (X,Y,Z, TOTAL_CNT, TOTAL_AMT)
SELECT X,Y,Z, TOTAL_CNT, TOTAL_AMT
FROM(

SELECT A.X, A.Y, A.Z , COUNT(1) TOTAL_CNT, SUM(AMT) TOTAL_AMT
FROM AAA A WHERE A.X = 1 
GROUP BY A.X, A.Y, A.Z 
UNION ALL

SELECT B.X, B.Y, B.Z , COUNT(1), SUM(AMT)
FROM BBB B WHERE A.X = 1 
GROUP BY B.X, B.Y, B.Z

) ;

v_number := sql%rowcount;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_number );

END;
/
```

PS: This is for Oracle.

Comment: Could you help me do the same on DB2, I'm using DB2

Comment: I am not DB2 expert, but you can use `GET DIAGNOSTICS rcount = ROW_COUNT;`. Refer examples given at [this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005647.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-6-128&lang=en).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously answer is NO, but if you have some identifier which you know have been inserted, you can look for a join and check the time or even delete them.